# Different treatment of missing data by `pyspark.sql.functions.greatest` function

Tags: pandas, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.2.0 and wanted to understand how the `greatest` function deals with missing data.

Yet, I have two contradicting scenarios.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'a': [1, 2, 3],
        'b': [-1.0, 0.5, 2.7],
        'c': [3, None, 1]})
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, -1.0, 3), (2, 0.5, None), (3, 2.7, 1)], ['a', 'b', 'c'])


df1.withColumn('max', F.greatest(F.col('a'), F.col('b'), F.col('c'))).show()
df2.withColumn('max', F.greatest(df2.a, df2.b, df2.c)).show()
```

The first one yields this:

```
+---+----+---+---+
|  a|   b|  c|max|
+---+----+---+---+
|  1|-1.0|3.0|3.0|
|  2| 0.5|NaN|NaN|
|  3| 2.7|1.0|3.0|
+---+----+---+---+
```

While the second:

```
+---+----+----+---+
|  a|   b|   c|max|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|-1.0|   3|3.0|
|  2| 0.5|null|2.0|
|  3| 2.7|   1|3.0|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Ideally, I want nulls to be skipped and when testing I stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first spark dataframe is created using the panda dataframe where none is getting converted to Nan which is the default conversion of panda api for missing data.

In the second case you are using spark api with the raw data and which always converted to null for the missing data

In python null object is represented by none. You can not use null in python instead of it none is used

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, if I understand correctly when I pull data from hive it will behave as in the second scenario. Right? Because I'm skipping the pandas step.

Comment: Yes it will convert to null